# How to change the squad parameter of ticket from FB Python API

Tags: python, fogbugz, fogbugz-api, fogbugz-on-demand

I am using Fogbugz Python API, and I want to change the `squad` parameter of my ticket.

Did the below change through Fogbugz UI.

```
<sChanges>
Squad changed from (No Value) to 'x'.
</sChanges>
```

but when I am doing,

```
fb.edit(ixBug=75268,sSquad="Security and Compliance")
```

It does not seem to change anything, anyone knows how to go about it? How do I make the change to `squad`?